# Magento Reindex data event

Tags: magento-1.9

i want to create a module for auto generate meta data(like this:Buy {product name} for Rs {price} at sitename.com | New Book | Authorised seller for {publihser}) on reindex data so what is observer event which run on Reindex data

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link could help: http://rabee.me/codes/magento/cheatsheet/1.9/

See 'end_index_events'.

Comment: That link is no longer working for some reason but i did find this: https://huztechbuzz.wordpress.com/2014/04/26/complete-list-of-all-events-in-magento/

Comment: and this: https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/